# How to manipulate more than 21bit Decimal/Integer Number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, binary

I want to manipulate a 32bit binary number in order to count the amount of "1".
The input for my function is binary number like this 11111111111111111111111111111101.
The problem is when this number is received from my function it generates a complete different binary string example ('10001100001111011110111110110001111011011011100110001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000') or an exponential number. Both situations do not allow me to manipulate and work with a binary number imput.

Here is my code:

```
var countingOnes = function (n) {
  let binx = { n: `${n.toString(2)}` };

  console.log(binx);

  let counter = 0;

  for (let j = 0; j < binx.n.length; j++) {
    if (binx.n.charAt(j) === "0") {
      counter = counter;
    } else {
      counter = counter + 1;
    }
  }

  console.log(counter);
};

countingOnes(11111111111111111111111111111101);
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `11111111111111111111111111111101` is not a "32bit binary number". That's an integer(*) consisting of 32 `1`s and `0`s

Comment: is it possible to take an equivalent decimal number? For example, taking `6` as input instead of `110`

Comment: Hello @Suman in this case the input must be the integer itself.

Comment: @MarcosLemos Yes, if it will help you with your problem, than I can give you some optimized solution. Just wanted to confirm from your end, whether you can use it or not.

Comment: That is a good point @Andreas. I still do not know how to handle the integer and transform it in a string or object. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Did you mean `countingOnes(0b11111111111111111111111111111101)` (a binary, not decimal, integer literal)?

Comment: Hi @Bergi, what I mean is countingOnes(11111111111111111111111111111101). According to our colleague above an Integer consisting of `1` and `0`.

Comment: @MarcosLemos Then your colleague is wrong (or you did misunderstand them). The decimal value `110` is the same as the binary value `0b1101110`, whereas another binary value `0b1111011` is for example equivalent to `123`. Do you still consider that to consist of zeros and ones?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, the input to the function should be only zeros and ones according to the example 11111111111111111111111111111101. Thanks

Comment: @MarcosLemos If you accept that `123` consists of zeroes and ones, then surely you also understand that when passing the decimal number `11111111111111111111111111111101` it has a different bit pattern than `0b11111111111111111111111111111101`?

Comment: @Bergi, yes! They are different and my issue is to manipulate the decimal/integer number ```11111111111111111111111111111101```.

Comment: @MarcosLemos Well if you want to manipulate a decimal, then use `n.toString(10)` instead of `n.toString(2)`, but of course nothing guarantees your function gets passed numbers whose decimal representation consists of only ones and zeros.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi! You are right!  Unfortunatelly I have tried ```n.toString(10)``` but the output is a exponential number and I still cannot manipulate de number to count the amount of ```1``` :-(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your goal is but Bitwise operators may be what you are looking.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND_assignment

they allow you to perform bit manipulation to the actual numbers. Is there a specific reason why you need the output as a string?

have a look at this I have not fully tested it but seems to work assuming a 32bit integer...

`function count1s(num = 5986) {

  //parse to an integer
  const integer = parseInt(num);

  //loop through and count
  let count = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {

    let test = integer >> (32 - i);

    if((test % 2) === 1) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  //return the results
  return count;
}

console.log(count1s());`

Comment: Hello @StevenWillis! I really appreciate your suggestion. However if the input is a long integer of ´1´ and ´0´  as I have stated above your suggestion do not work properly. By the way, it is not madatory to transform to a string. We can also manipulate an array or an object. :-)

Answer (score 0):

after a few changes I have applied the following solution:

```
var countingOnes = function (n) {
let binx = n.toString(2);

  let counter = 0;

  for (let j = 0; j < binx.length; j++) {
    if (binx.charAt(j) === "0") {
      counter = counter;
    } else {
      counter = counter + 1;
    }
  }

  return counter;
};
countingOnes("11111111111111111111111111111101");
```

Instead of considering the input as a number of 32 caracteres, I have considered the input as a string of 32 caracteres. Easier to manipulate.
Thanks everyone for the contribution and suggestions!